# Accessing an object's parameter from an object inside it

Tags: .net, vb.net, basic

I'm coding a program in which I have a class inside another class. I need to know if I can access properties of the external class from the internal one.

Something like this:

```
Module mod1

    Public Class c1
        Public var1 As Integer = 3

        Public Class c2

            Public Sub doSomething()
                'I need to access var1 from here. Is it possible?
            End Sub

        End Class

    End Class

End Module
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

EDIT: Example of what I want to do

```
Dim obj1 As New c1 'Let's suppose that the object is properly initialized
Dim obj2 As New obj1.c2 'Let's suppose that the object is properly initialized

obj2.doSomething() 'Here, I want to affect ONLY the var1 of obj1. Would that be possible?
```

Comment: You need an instance of `c1` to be able to access `var1` or you need to make it a shared variable.

Comment: @Saragis I can't make it Shared because every instance of c1 will have a different value, and I can't either instance c1 because I don't want a new object, but the one that the c2 object is inside. In case I'm not explaining myself properly, I've added an example in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still going to need to create a link between those two objects somewhere. Here is an example of how you could do it.

```
Dim obj1 As New c1
Dim obj2 As New c2(obj1)

obj2.doSomething()
```

*doSomething* can now affect both variables defined in *c1* and *c2*. Implementation:

```
Public Class c1
    Public var1 As Integer = 3
End Class

Public Class c2
    Private linkedC1 As c1

    Public Sub New(ByVal linkedC1 As c1)
        Me.linkedC1 = linkedC1
    End Sub

    Public Sub doSomething()
        'I need to access var1 from here. Is it possible?
        linkedC1.var1 += 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Then that's what I'm going to do. Thank you so much!